# Grails - attempting to include HTPPBuilder - Linkage error

Tags: grails, ivy, dependency-management

When I run `grails install-dependency`, I get this.

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for
    a different type with name "org/xml/sax/SAXParseException"
```

What's wrong? I've not used grails dependency management before, and this is rather cryptic.

```
repositories {        
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
     runtime 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.0'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an xml-apis clash,

Try

```
dependencies {
     runtime 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.0'{
         excludes 'xml-apis'
     }
}
```

Comment: This lets it build, supposedly, but when I try to use HTTPBuilder, I get class not resolved.

My IDE also shows that I don't have the appropriate library when I attempt to auto-import or import manually. Thoughts?

Comment: xalan is another lib that can sometimes cause trouble, does HttpBuilder depend on that?

Comment: HTTPBuilder. It seems like IntelliJ just isn't picking it up, or I don't know what I need to do to make the library visible. I can run with grails run-app, but I'm getting IDE errors.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I do not need "runtime" as the build specifier. Drr.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770819/grails-xom-linkageerror-saxparserexception